# Files in Windows 7 case-insensitive?

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are all versions of windows case insensitive?](https://superuser.com/questions/165975/are-all-versions-of-windows-case-insensitive)

I've got 2 files on a Unix server which I tried to ftp (using FileZilla) to a Windows 7 machine - `tdda.png` and `TDDA.png` - initially FileZilla complained that `TDDA.png` was already a file when I tried to transfer `TDDA.png`, so I renamed it to `TDDA2.png` before transferring it.  I then tried to rename it back to `TDDA.png` in Windows and get the notification:

"Do you want to rename 'TDDA2.png to ''tdda(2).png? There is already a file with the same name in this location"

Has Windows 7 got some case-insensitivity built in somewhere? I've never experienced it with any other version of Windows...

Comment: Windows has ALWAYS been case-insensitive.  It's one of the discerning ("user-friendly") features that make it different than systems like *nix (actually it predates Windows to DOS).

Comment: Windows is case-preserving, but case-insensitive as far as most file operations go. It'll remember the case used when you create (or rename) a file, but for all other operations the case of the filename given is ignored and does not need to match the file stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Windows is case insensitive, but by enabling the "POSIX subsystem" case sensitive filenames are possible. This feature is used in the "Microsoft Windows Services for UNIX" (Windows acts as an NFS file server and other).

See Stackoverflow question [How to make an ntfs case sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979544/how-to-make-an-ntfs-case-sensitive)