# Windows 10 ignoring case in filename

Tags: windows-10, file-management

I tried to transfer two files from a computer cluster named `test_A.txt` and `test_a.txt` onto my windows 10 computer. I can only transfer one unless I rename or overwrite the other file.

If I run this python code on my windows 10 computer I also end up with only one file:

```
with open("test_A.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("Test_A\n")
    
with open("test_a.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("Test_a\n")
```

I'm not sure if this is the normal behavior in windows 10 or if it's some strange setting I have.

Not sure if this has been asked before but couldn't find it.

Comment: Related: [Are all versions of Windows case insensitive?](https://superuser.com/questions/165975/are-all-versions-of-windows-case-insensitive)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows is case-aware, but not case-sensitive by default.
So, by default it considers those to be 'the same name'.

You can, since 1803, enable case-sensitivity per directory.
See [How to Enable Case Sensitive File and Folder Names on Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/354220/how-to-enable-case-sensitive-folders-on-windows-10/)

Note, some apps cannot handle case-sensitivity well, so don't just blanket convert everything. Be minimal.